# Organising a Lunene Directory

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I have a set of records.  Each record can have multiple skills and a single state.

So you might have a record of skills a, b and c and a state of Victoria.

I need to be able to search the directory for any records that have say skill a in Victoria or skill a and c in Victoria.

I'm having trouble creating an effective directory that will allow me to search in the manner I want.

At first i created a directory with `skills: a b c state:vic`
then i tried `skills: a,b,c state:vic`

But searching these is not giving me the correct results.  In fact when i have a query;

```
skills:a,b AND state:vic,
skills: a OR b AND state:vic,
skills: a OR skills:b AND state:vic
```

the above all return a set of records for `skills: a AND state:vic`.

Any thought?

**EDIT**

Since posting this I have gotten it to work but am unsure if this is the right approach.

I have combined all the skills into a single field and space seperated them.  The skills are in GUID format.

Then in my search method I do this;

```
queryString = "skills:(skill1 OR skill2 OR skill3) AND state:Vic";
Query query = parser.Parse(queryString);
```

This works fine and it's very quick but is creating a queryString really the way to go with this or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BooleanQuery : http://geekswithblogs.net/rgupta/archive/2009/01/07/lucene-multifield-searches.aspx

Comment: I did try that yeah and had exactly the same results.  I have had some success since posting this and have added that to my question

Answer (score 0):

You could build your `BooleanQuery` directly, instead of going via a `QueryParser`. This requires that you differentate skills- and state input fields when presenting your search interface to your users.

```
var skillQuery = new BooleanQuery {
    { new TermQuery(new Term("skills", "skill1")), Occur.SHOULD },
    { new TermQuery(new Term("skills", "skill2")), Occur.SHOULD },
    { new TermQuery(new Term("skills", "skill3")), Occur.SHOULD }
};

var query = new BooleanQuery() {
    { skillQuery, Occur.MUST },
    { new TermQuery(new Term("state", "Vic")), Occur.MUST }
};
// query = "+(skills:skill1 skills:skill2 skills:skill3) +state:Vic"
```

Allowing freetext entries when searching for skills still require a call to `QueryParser.Parse`.

```
var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);
var skillParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "skills", analyzer);
var skillQuery = skillParser.Parse("skill1, skill2, skill3");
var query = new BooleanQuery() {
    { skillQuery, Occur.MUST },
    { new TermQuery(new Term("state", "Vic")), Occur.MUST }
};
// query = "+(skills:skill1 skills:skill2 skills:skill3) +state:Vic"
```